# react: index.js or app.js don't seem to be importing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

after some time, i'm creating a react app, and i've just set up a skeleton, but it doesn't show up.

i've done the steps, npx create, npm install and start.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```
import React from "react";
import Main from "./components/Main"

const App =()=> {
  return (
    <Main/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";
import "./Main.scss";

const Main =()=> {
    <div id="main">
        <div className="gameboard">
        </div>
        <div className="console">
        </div>
    </div>
}

export default Main;
```

using inspector, there are no divs from Main component in the browser. just the root.

Comment: If you open the dev console, you should have gotten a `console.error` about this issue. You must return either jsx or `null`. `undefined` is not a valid value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because you don't return the main jsx

```
import React from "react";
import "./Main.scss";

const Main =()=> {
 return (
  <div id="main">
    <div className="gameboard">
    </div>
    <div className="console">
    </div>
</div>
)
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: i forgot the return, thanks

Comment: sometimes it just happened. Have a nice day